# OpenGl & Android: Rotating the Gyro by 90 degrees

Tags: android, opengl-es-2.0, gyroscope

Good evening all

I am trying to make a 3D splitscreen rendering view for devices like Google CardBoard, OpenDive, vRase etc

I am rotating the view based on the gryo so that when a person moves their head, the rendered view changes.

Using the values from the gyro, my view is pointing at the floor.  If I add 90 to the Gryo reading for the X it works but because the value is -90 to + 90, the whole thing gets messed up

```
float currentZ = (androidSensor.getRoll() ) ;
        float currentX = (androidSensor.getPitch());
        float currentY = (androidSensor.getAzimuth() );

        Log.i("TAG", "x: " + currentX + " z " + currentZ + " y " + currentY);

        //Matrix.rotateM(mCamera.mHMatrix, 0, currentY, 0, -1,0);
        Matrix.rotateM(mCamera.mHMatrix, 0, currentX , 1, 0,0);
```

Should I actually rotate the render by 90 instead?

Comment: What exactly gets messed up when it hits -90/90?

Comment: It was the sensor reading was wrong and not based on device orientation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sensor reading was not taking in to consideration of the device orientation.